# Javascript Math Object Methods - negatives to zero

Tags: javascript, math, negative-number

in Javascript I can't seem to find a method to set negatives to zero?

-90 becomes 0
-45 becomes 0
0 becomes 0
90 becomes 90

Is there anything like that? I have just rounded numbers.

Answer (score 251, accepted):

Just do something like

```
value = value < 0 ? 0 : value;
```

or

```
if (value < 0) value = 0;
```

or

```
value = Math.max(0, value);
```

Comment: Quick JSPerf shows value = value < 0 ? 0 : value; is on top http://jsperf.com/negatives-to-zero

Comment: I like the `Math.max` one the most, because it only requires referencing `value` once

Comment: In a more fair benchmark, Math.max wins probably because it was already instantiated once. https://jsbench.me/tbkmm8varf/1

Comment: @insign - I'm getting different results every time I run your benchmark - sometimes a 3 way tie.  Seems like readability and consistency are more important factors if the margins are so close between them.

Answer (score 80):

I suppose you could use `Math.max()`.

```
var num = 90;
num = Math.max(0,num) || 0; // 90

var num = -90;
num = Math.max(0,num) || 0; // 0
```

Comment: This one should be the accepted answer in my opinion. Just saying... :)

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that both `Math.max(0, NaN)` and `Math.max(0, undefined)` return `NaN` so you may want to do something along these lines: `Math.max(0, num) || 0`

Comment: What's the `~~`?

Comment: @RedGuy11 The `~~` is obstrusive and wrong, it converts it to binary. Which in turn makes it work ONLY for integers: `~~.1 == 0`
Not sure why this is upvoted so often, no one sees how wrong it is?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to be clever:

```
num = (num + Math.abs(num)) / 2;
```

However, `Math.max` or a conditional operator would be much more understandable.
Also, this has precision issues for large numbers.

Answer (score 4):

```
function makeNegativeNumberZero(num) {
  return !!Math.max(0, num);
}

// or 

function makeNegativeNumberZero(num) {
  return num < 0 ? 0 : num;
}
```

Comment: zero is neither positive nor negative, your function should be renamed according to that

Comment: I wouldn't recommend extending a native object. it's a bad practice.
refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/14034242/11877987

Answer (score 3):

`x < 0 ? 0 : x` does the job .

Answer (score 0):

Remember the negative zero.

```
function isNegativeFails(n) {
    return n < 0;
}
function isNegative(n) {
    return ((n = +n) || 1 / n) < 0;
}
isNegativeFails(-0); // false
isNegative(-0); // true
Math.max(-0, 0); // 0
Math.min(-0, 0); // -0
```

Source: http://cwestblog.com/2014/02/25/javascript-testing-for-negative-zero/

Answer (score 0):

Well `value = Math.max(0,value)` is just neat but after 10 years, i just don't want one other nice method to go unmentioned.

```
value < 0 && (value = 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var num = 90;
num = Math.max(0,num); // 90

var num = -90;
num =Math.max(0,num); //0
```

This method can be used

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.