# how to convert an array element [ - 0 ] to a string?

Tags: javascript, numbers

I am trying to convert an array of numbers to an array of strings and get the first character in each element of the array. Tell me what I am doing wrong that I get "0" and not "-" in the last element?

function example

```
function invert(array) {

  let q = array.map(i => i.toString()[0])
}
invert([-10,8,-2,-0])
```

result  Array(4) [ "-", "8", "-", "0" ]

Comment: Simply because `(-0).toString()` is `"0"`? String conversion ignores the peculiarity that negative zero is and handles any zero as 0.

Comment: `(-0).toLocaleString()` appears to be `"-0"`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon: Of course, you'd need to verify it will behave that way in all locales (I don't know of any guarantees there), and/or be okay with the formatting differing by locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this answer [Are +0 and -0 the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223359/are-0-and-0-the-same) you can use `Object.is` to check if a number is `-0`

```js
function invert(array) {
  return array.map(i => Object.is(i, -0) ? '-' : i.toString()[0])
}
console.log(invert([-10,8,-2,-0]))
```

Answer (score 3):

[Per MDN's `Number.toString` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString):

> Both `0` and `-0` have `"0"` as their string representation.

If you want it to have a negative sign, you'll have to special case `-0` (this [can be harder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7223395/364696) [than it seems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48222535/364696)).